# A request to the boss

Tags: politeness

When I have something  I want to ask my boss, is it appropriate to say it like this? 

• I have a request to you. Would you please ...?


Is there any more appropriate or polite way to say that?

Answer (score 1):

The first sentence should say "request for you", not "to you".
If you want to make it sound more polite, you might add more words and a note of hesitancy. For example,
"Excuse me, [boss|Ms. X|Mr. Y], but I wonder if you could do something for me. My request is...".